# How to resolve "use of package without a selector error"

Tags: go, package

I am using a package: [ccs08](https://github.com/ing-bank/zkrp/tree/master/ccs08)
In my main, I am importing the package and using some of its functions. I have followed the usage from the unit tests given:

```
package main

import(
 "fmt"
 "math/big"
 "crypto/rand"
 "zkrp/ccs08"
 "zkrp/crypto/bn256"
)

func main(){

        var (
            r *big.Int
            s []int64
        )
        s = make([]int64, 4)
        s[0] = 12
        s[1] = 42
        s[2] = 61
        s[3] = 71
        p, _ := ccs08.SetupSet(s)
        r, _ = rand.Int(rand.Reader, bn256.Order)
        proof_out, _ := ccs08.ProveSet(12, r, p)
        result, _ := ccs08.VerifySet(&proof_out, &p)
        if result != true {
            fmt.Println("not verified")
        }
}
```

I then have a similar main file,main2, where I am using another set of functions from the same package. **This does NOT work**

```
package main

import(
 "fmt"
 "math/big"
 "crypto/rand"
 "zkrp/ccs08"
 "zkrp/crypto/bn256"
)

func main(){

    var (

        result bool
        zkrp ccs08
    )
    zkrp.Setup(347184000, 599644800)
    zkrp.x = new(big.Int).SetInt64(419835123)
    zkrp.r, _ = rand.Int(rand.Reader, bn256.Order)
    e := zkrp.Prove()
    result, _ = zkrp.Verify()
    if result != true {
        fmt.println("not verified")
    }

}
```

---

I am getting this error:
./main2.go:7:  imported and not used: "zkrp/ccs08".

./main2.go:16: use of package ccs08 without selector.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first file, everything works because the code is using public members of the `ccs08` package. However, this is not the case for the second file.

You mentioned the code in the second file is copied from [here](https://github.com/ing-bank/zkrp/blob/master/ccs08/ccs08_test.go#L149-L165).

To understand why the code does not work when pasted into a main method outside the `ccs08` package, you need to understand what it is doing in its original location. Specifically this part:

```
var (
    result bool
    zkrp   ccs08
)
```

In the original location (inside the `ccs08` package) there is a private struct type named `ccs08`. The declaration can be seen [here](https://github.com/ing-bank/zkrp/blob/master/ccs08/ccs08.go#L354-L358). What the above code is doing is creating a variable named `zkrp` the type of which is the private struct type `ccs08`. Then, the various functions called on the variable are methods bound to this private struct (you can see the methods [here](https://github.com/ing-bank/zkrp/blob/master/ccs08/ccs08.go#L363-L427)).

Now, in the code you posted (after pasting into a location outside the `ccs08` package), there is no way to access the private `ccs08` struct (I can't even find a public method which returns it in  the zkrp source code). So, what Go sees when it tries to execute this code is a typo (where it thinks you are trying to write something of the form `package.Member`):

```
// this looks like you wanted to declare a variable with type:
// "ccs08.SomeType" but forgot to write ".SomeType"
// Thus Go gives the error: "use of package ccs08 without selector"
var zkrp ccs08
```

And the "imported and not used" error is because the `ccs08` package isn't used in a valid way anywhere in the code.

The code which you copied is honestly pretty confusing with all the reusing of the strings `ccs08` and `zkrp` for naming of different things. I hope this clears it up a bit.

Comment: And just to add, if you are using [this library](https://github.com/ing-bank/zkrp) then the functions you want are in the `ccs08` package so you will want to import `"zkrp/ccs08"` and reference the package with `ccs08` in the code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already tried importing zkrp/ccs08, then I comment the variable zkrp and directly use ccs08.Setup(), but when I try to do this, it says undefined ccs08.Setup ( gives same error for all the ccs08 functions in main 2)
I am wondering what's the use of zkrp variable here .. I borrowed this code from the unit tests of ccs08 package ( you may check it in the file ccs08_test.go at the very end).

Comment: After seeing that unit test file, I can see that my previous answer was wrong. I hope the updated answer helps.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I do understand the problem now but still don't know how to resolve this. How to access this private struct in main?

Comment: With the `zkrp` code as it is it's not possible. The only options you have now are 1. Try and find a way to do what you need to do using only the public functions. 2. Copy the `ccs08` struct code and paste it into your own codebase.

Comment: Thanks for your time and explanation, helped a lot